# Error installing SinchRTC in termninal while trying to install pod

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

pod install
Analyzing dependencies
Adding spec repo `trunk` with CDN `https://cdn.cocoapods.org/`

CocoaPods 1.11.3 is available.
To update use: `sudo gem install cocoapods`

For more information, see https://blog.cocoapods.org and the CHANGELOG for this version at https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/releases/tag/1.11.3

Downloading dependencies
Installing Alamofire (5.2.1)
Installing AppAuth (1.4.0)
Installing CardIO (5.4.1)
Installing Crashlytics (3.14.0)
Installing CropViewController (2.6.0)
Installing FBSDKCoreKit (8.2.0)
Installing FBSDKLoginKit (8.2.0)
Installing FBSDKShareKit (8.2.0)
Installing FLAnimatedImage (1.0.12)
Installing Fabric (1.10.2)
Installing Firebase (7.3.0)
Installing FirebaseAnalytics (7.3.0)
Installing FirebaseAuth (7.3.0)
Installing FirebaseCore (7.3.0)
Installing FirebaseCoreDiagnostics (7.3.0)
Installing FirebaseCrashlytics (7.3.0)
Installing FirebaseDatabase (7.3.0)
Installing FirebaseInstallations (7.3.0)
Installing FirebaseInstanceID (7.3.0)
Installing FirebaseMessaging (7.3.0)
Installing GTMAppAuth (1.1.0)
Installing GTMSessionFetcher (1.5.0)
Installing GoogleAppMeasurement (7.3.0)
Installing GoogleDataTransport (8.1.0)
Installing GoogleMaps (4.1.0)
Installing GoogleSignIn (5.0.2)
Installing GoogleUtilities (7.1.1)
Installing HandyJSON (5.0.2)
Installing IQKeyboardManagerSwift (6.5.6)
Installing LiveChat (2.0.21)
Installing NVActivityIndicatorView (5.1.1)
Installing PromisesObjC (1.2.12)
Installing RaveSDK (2.2.1)
Installing SDWebImage (4.4.8)
Installing SinchRTC (4.2.6)

[!] Error installing SinchRTC
[!] /usr/bin/curl -f -L -o /var/folders/8f/svmsxhn17cn45qb1c5mzh7j80000gn/T/d20220319-9125-1ql2jnh/file.tbz https://download.sinch.com/ios/4.2.6/Sinch-iOS-4.2.6-960abb8a.tar.bz2 --create-dirs --netrc-optional --retry 2 -A 'CocoaPods/1.11.2 cocoapods-downloader/1.5.1'

% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 403

[!] Automatically assigning platform `iOS` with version `11.0` on target `UserApp` because no platform was specified. Please specify a platform for this target in your Podfile. See `https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform`

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Any luck?